# Validate on select while choosing files for upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate file types as soon as the files are choosen for upload

Below is my html code

```
<label> <input type="file" id="image" name="upload[]" multiple="multiple" onclick="validateFileExtension()" />
```

Validation code

```
function validateFileExtension() {
       var ext = $('#my-file-selector').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg', 'pdf']) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');
}
}
```

But it is not validating as soon as the files are selected. Only upon submitting the form, the validation happens. i have other a jquery for validation on submit. I need to validate on select. Please help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick is not firing after you select a file. using onchange instead works.

```js
function validateFileExtension(element) {
  var files = $(element)[0].files;
  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var ext = files[i].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'pdf']) == -1) {
      console.log('invalid extension!', ext);
    } else {
      console.log('valid extension :)', ext);
    }
  }
}

function validateForm(form) {
  validateFileExtension(form.image);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="file" id="image" name="upload[]" multiple="multiple" onchange="validateFileExtension(this)" />
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="validateForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes for a single file, but not when two files are selected and one is right file type. It not your code it this `var ext = $(element).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();`

Comment: It has too do with the way IE prints it value to the input and HTML 5 multiple attribute.

Comment: Thanks all it works !! another question can i use the same for form submit validation too ??

Comment: on form submit button you would use onclick and and run validation for the entire form there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onchange` and need to loop through the files array if using the `multiple` attribute

```js
function validateFileExtension(element) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
    // make sure in all browsers were just looking at the file name 
    var ext = element.files[i].name.split('.')[1].toLowerCase(); 
    if ($.inArray(ext, ['gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'pdf']) == -1) {
      element.value = ""; // clear the input field
      alert('invalid extension!'); // now alert user
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>File</label>
<input type="file" id="image" name="upload[]" multiple="multiple" onchange="validateFileExtension(this);" />
```